# Hibernate Mapping One To Many Relationship:Parent's PK to Child's FK 

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a classic one to many relationship and while saving it with Hibernate, I am not able to pass parent's PK column value to Child's FK column.
**Parent Class**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int holdingPK;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="holding",targetEntity=PolicyType.class,fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@XmlElement(name = "Policy")
private Set<PolicyType> policy;
```

**Child Class**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int policyPK;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="HoldingFK",nullable = false)
private HoldingType holding;
```

Here `HoldingPK`is a auto generated sequence column which represents primary key. Value gets generated when I insert a Holding row. So  I want to pass HoldingPK value to child's `HoldingFK` column on the fly.
**Test Code**

```
HoldingType obj = new HoldingType();
obj.setCurrencyTypeCode("6");
obj.setHoldingKey("123");
Set<PolicyType> set = new TreeSet<PolicyType>();
PolicyType policy = new PolicyType();
policy.setJurisdiction("Haha");
set.add(policy);
obj.setPolicy(set);
session.save(obj);
transaction.commit();
```

So I am able to pass Child's other values to Child Table column, just Parent PK is not reaching to Child's FK column.

Here I am persisting XML document values to database. For this I am marshalling XML to Java Objects using JAXB then persisting objects using Hibernate. In this way I am reusing JAXB generated classes with Hibernate and these PK and FK elements do not exist on XML. These are specific to Database.

Comment: You should add more info on how you build your object instances before em.persist(). Hibernate should take care of all of this.

Comment: How do you persist the parent/child?  I think that using mappedBy is equivalent to inverse=true in Hibernate - meaning that the Child is the "owner" of the relationship so you have to persist the children to set the FK properly.

Comment: @nomoa I have added the test code. Here all other child column values are passing perfectly just that FK column is getting populated with Parent's PK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply forgot to initialise the owning side of the bidirectional association. You only initialized the inverse side (the one which has the `mappedBy` attribute). Hibernate only considers the owning side to know if an association exists or not (the side without the `mappedBy` attribute).

Add this to your code (before the holding is saved):

```
policy.setHolding(obj);
```

Side note: your code would be much more readable if you named the `policy` field (and accessors) `policies`. There are many of them, so it should have a plural form.

Comment: @You are absolutely right. This is the part I am missing to get the perfect object model but JAXB doesn't know about it. How to resolve that?

Comment: You can set the parent in afterunmarshall caller of the entity. see https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_cyclic_references_to_XML.html