# One to many hibernate bidirectional mapping with JAXB generated classes

Tags: hibernate, jaxb

Is it possible to tell JAXB to create Hibernate bidirectional mapping?
Holding class can have many Policy children. 
To pass Parent's PK to Child's FK, I have to set

```
policy.setHolding(holding)
```

and then I can say

```
session.save(holding)
```

But it doesn't work when I am marshalling XML to Holding object using JAXB.
More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452388/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-relationshipparents-pk-to-childs-fk/11453445)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You may be interested in the `@XmlInverseReference` extension in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) for supporting this use case.  Below is an example:

**Customer**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="customer", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Address address;

}
```

**Address**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@Entity
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID")
    @MapsId
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="address")
    private Customer customer;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html

Comment: I was digging thru JAXB(MOXy) wiki and found the same. I think you answered the same issue earlier on SO. Its working for me now. Thanks a lot.